# Bundle app with files located in internal storage directory instead of assets directory?

Tags: android, android-file, android-storage

I am building an app which will contain media files that are bundled with the application. 
Users will also be able to download additional media files at runtime.

I want to store the downloaded files in the application's internal storage directory. 
Is it possible to "bundle" the initial files in such a way that it is also stored in the internal storage directory, or will I need to place them in `assets`, and thus have two different ways of accessing my media files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to "bundle" the initial files in such a way that it is also stored in the internal storage directory

If you are looking to have them be placed there automatically, then no, there is no option for this.

> will I need to place them in assets, and thus have two different ways of accessing my media files?

You are welcome to copy the assets to the filesystem yourself (see `AssetManager`). You would treat the filesystem as the "system of record" and only copy things there if needed (e.g., first run of the app, after user does "Clear Data").

Comment: Ok thanks, I did wonder about this - but my media files are very large - so if I understand correctly I will actually have two files then, one in assets and one in the internal storage, doubling the amount of storage I us?

Comment: @HPage: The assets (usually) are compressed in the APK, so it will not be a strict doubling of the disk space. However, it will take up more space than just the files themselves, and depending on compressibility it could be double (or thereabouts). You could leave them as assets and not make the filesystem copy, but it does mean a bit of incremental code. Depending on your app functionality, I can see up to four different sources of media: assets, files, content (`ACTION_PICK`, `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, etc.), and Web. Possibly more if you are going to get into `rtsp` or other schemes.

Comment: @HPage: So, an abstraction layer is likely to be useful, even beyond this assets scenario. Treat assets as just another source of media with an other implementation of some API that you define.